# ¿Como leer correos no leídos de una bandeja de entrada en asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Mi objetivo es leer archivos adjuntos de un formato especifico. Y me gustaría saber como hacerlo. Si alguien sabe, se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder al mail lo haces por medio de protocolos como ser POP3 o IMAP

[System.Net.Pop3 POP3 Client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Pop3/)

hay libreria un poco mas completas

[Mail.dll - .NET email component](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mail.dll/)

que permiten acceder a pop3 o imap

Con pop3 no deberias tener problema con los leidos porque una vez que accedes al mail se elimina del servidor, ya que el mail se descarga al cliente.
Pero si vas a tener problemas con IMAP ya que estos quedan en el servidor, quizas deberias ver una vez leido si se puede mover a otra carpeta y que no queden en la bandeja de entrada.

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tuttini, estuve probando con POP3, pero me lee todos los correos, los enviados, los de la bandeja de entrada, los no deseados, y yo necesito leer solamente los que no han sido leídos exclusivamente de la bandeja de entrada. En este caso, que me convendría. Y si tuviera un ejemplo de como hacerlo, te lo agradecería mucho